# Get the probabity of a specific word in Keras LSTM model

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, nlp, lstm

I trained a w2v model and a keras LSTM model on top of it:

```
pretrained_weights = w2v_model.wv.syn0
vocab_size, emdedding_size = pretrained_weights.shape

keras_lstm_model = Sequential()
keras_lstm_model.add(Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size, output_dim = emdedding_size, weights = [pretrained_weights]))
keras_lstm_model.add(LSTM(units = emdedding_size))
keras_lstm_model.add(Dense(units = vocab_size))
keras_lstm_model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
keras_lstm_model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['mae','acc'])
```

Now, I have a sentence

> "This is my "

and I want to get the probability for the word

> "Hat"

.

I can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your output of the model has `vocab_size` neurons. If you call `keras_lstm_model.predict` you get the different probabilities for each word to succeed the sequence. The question is which probability do you need?  If you need one where the sum of all probabilities in a prediction is 1 then you should replace your last activation function with softmax.